# How to Bind two Models to a Single view

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I have a View in Apache Velocity where i have to bind my two Model Objects
first One is the Page that needs to load and second is the User Preferences like language, and Other such Filters.
Now the problem is the Page which is loaded is returned dynamically by an Generic Controller which each page extends
On the other hand the UserPreference Page is returned by a class that returns the Model seperately
In my vm page i use #springBind("Modelname"); for my userPreference Page but still the binding is not done
Whereas the First Pages are binded properly
How can i bind 2 models in a single VM page

Comment: additional info : The UserPreference is a fade in fadeout page that appears only when u hover over an icon but is loaded whenever the page is loaded

Comment: Without see little of your implementation is hard to help you.

Comment: can i have two models binded to a single view, also i dont want to have a base class and add the two models to it and then bind the base class to view because it will affect the load time